# Moving a view on Android using objectAnimator, getting a 24dp(72p) offset

Tags: android, objectanimator

I am trying to move a button in android using ObjectAnimator. I want the view to move just so that it does not overlap with the previous location and not more. So when moving the button down I calculate the new location like this new_location = Current_location_of_view + view_height. And when moving up: new_location = Current_location_of_view + view_height. But for this to work properly, I have to add a 24dp(72p) offset upward, I do this by subtracting 72 when getting the current view's location. Where is this offset coming from?
My guess is that the view.getLocationOnScreen() function has a different y axis starting point than the ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "y", new_location) function but I have no idea why. How should this be done properly?

I am using this code:

```
private void moveViewUpMinimum(View view, int viewHeight){
    int currentViewLocation = getViewLocation(view);
    Log.e("Actual location", String.valueOf(currentViewLocation));
    if(currentViewLocation >viewHeight){
        //if there is enough space on top of the screen
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "y", currentViewLocation-viewHeight);
        Log.e("Set location:", String.valueOf(currentViewLocation-viewHeight));
        objectAnimator.setDuration(100);
        objectAnimator.start();
    }
    else{
        //if no more room move the view down
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "y", screenHeight-viewHeight);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(100);
        objectAnimator.start();
    }
}
private void moveViewDownMinimum(View view, int viewHeight){
    int currentViewLocation = getViewLocation(view);
    Log.e("Actual location", String.valueOf(currentViewLocation));
    if(screenHeight - currentViewLocation >= 2*viewHeight){
        //if there is enough space on the bottom of the screen
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "y", currentViewLocation+viewHeight);
        Log.e("Set location:", String.valueOf(currentViewLocation+viewHeight));
        objectAnimator.setDuration(100);
        objectAnimator.start();
    }
    else{
        //if no more room move the view up
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "y", 0);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(100);
        objectAnimator.start();
    }
}
private int getViewLocation(View view){
    int buttonLoc[] = {0, 0};
    view.getLocationOnScreen(buttonLoc);
    return buttonLoc[1]-72;//where does this offset come from???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using view.getY() instead of view.getLocationOnScreen(). The getLocationOnScreen() function returned a value 72px more than the view.getY(), and I guess that value is my status bar. I should have used the getY() function from the start since that is the value I am using in the ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "y", newLocation) function.